# Python Selenium driver by CSS selector inside of a loop

Tags: python, selenium

I am scraping a page heavy with JS, where I select a js button

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.u-textColorDarker').click()
```

which displays a from. Inside that form, some info is displayed, but to get all the content there is a button ("show more") that  needs to be clicked n times to display all the content. When there is nothing else to show, the button disappears.

In this particular page, the button needs to be clicked 3 times. So a quick solution for my problem in:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.js-showMoreRecommends').click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.js-showMoreRecommends').click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.js-showMoreRecommends').click()
time.sleep(2)
```

Is there a way to put this in a loop, so the action is done inside a loop until the selector '.js-showMoreRecommends' is no longer present?

Comment: Sure, use ``while True:`` and break out of it when your condition is met

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insted of a while true loop you can try to while loop when the button is displayed

```
while driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.js-showMoreRecommends').is_displayed():
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.js-showMoreRecommends').click()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: this will work fine! yet it's recommended to use  `WebDriverWait` not `time.sleep`...

Answer (score 2):

As [@mike-scotty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4349415/mike-scotty) comented: "Use `while`"

It is recommended to use [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) and not `time.sleep()`.

Should look something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

while WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".js-showMoreRecommends"))):
    show_more = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".js-showMoreRecommends")))
    show_more.click()
```

Comment: Thank you Moshe, this solution got stuck in a loop. Jose Martinez version (below) worked well, although it does not useWebDriverWait, but time.sleep.

Comment: @LuisMiguel Glad to hear! you Should try using `WebDriverWait` more... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can using expected conditions.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url")

while not EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".js-showMoreRecommends")):
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.js-showMoreRecommends').click()
```

I am writing this from memory, but it should point you in the general direction.
The meat of this is the expected conditions method `EC.invisibility_of_element_located`. It will give you a boolean value to determine if it is gone yet.

Comment: Yeah we were writing posts about the same time.

Comment: Thank you Raven, this solution executed, but the buttons did not get clicked. Jose Martinez solution worked well. Not really sure why yours did not work. Thanks again, anyway

Comment: Probably just needed a different expected conditions selector. Glad you found a solution. Just know that one isn't deterministic, so if anything on the website changes your program will break.